# send Player-ID from OneSignal into Webview Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-webview, onesignal

I got a webview App in Android Studio with OneSignal working Ok.
for now I can only send push-notifications to all users, that is, not personalized.

To achieve the personalized push, i need to grab the Player-Id (UUID) from one signal into my webview/url so I can save it together with User profile in my database.

How can I send or make the "Player-id" visible to the webview so then maybe with ajax save it?

Answer (score 0):

You can save PlayerId to your database using an API.

**Second Method**,

If you have any unique Id (or something like that) associated with each user, you can set that ID as a tag to that user.[Here is the link to send Tag from android device](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--sendtag-).
And later you can send the notification based on that tag.

***THIS METHOD DOESN'T NEED PLAYER ID TO BE SAVED TO DATABASE.***

Notifications sent on the basis of tags will only be received by a user having that tag. For example, if you have a unique Id for each user, say userId (assuming userId is 1 for a particular user named John), then in your App, you can set tag like

> OneSignal.sendTag("userId", "1");

Then you can send a personalized notification based on that tag. [See here to send notifications based on tag](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-send-based-on-filters-tags-create-notification)

This notification will only be received by John.

Comment: can you show an example on how can I get the player ID with the Api?

Comment: How are you saving data in your database from your mobile App? and what platform are you using to send notifications (PHP, Android, python etc)

Comment: Im using PHP to send the notifications... and yes I wan to store the OneSignal-PlayerID into my database from the webview of an Android APP... Maybe putting the PlayerId as parameter in the url that the webview open.. like "site.com/?player_id=" & varPlayerId

Comment: Instead of opening a URL in webview, You can create an API using PHP and hit that from android device. But I would rather suggest sending notifications using the second method explained above as you don't have to save anything in your database.